# TinyMCE deleting content on paste

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm implementing TinyMCE in a website and I'm having issues with pasting, I wondered if anyone has had this bug before.

The basic structure inside the textarea is like this:

```
<h5>I am a heading</h5>
<p>I am a paragraph</p>
```

So when I first start editing if I place the cursor at the beginning of the editor and hit return a couple of times, then go back to the top to paste something in above the h5, the paste wipes out the h5.

When I look in the format dropdown before I paste, it says I'm still in a heading 5 and in the status bar it says 'Path: div » h3 » span.-span', is there a common solution to this problem?

Thanks

**Update** - I've just noticed this happens when I insert a line break instead of pasting too.

**Update 2** - It happens to the h5 if I have applied a colour to it within TinyMCE.

So I colour the heading, then put the cursor before it, press return  and try to paste/line break in the new space above and that clears it out. When coloured the html of the h5 looks like this:

```
<h5>
    <span style="color: #0000ff;">
        I am a heading
    </span>
</h5>
```

Comment: Is this happening in all browser. Try another one.

Comment: Same as you described works fine. I tested (FireFox) on http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php. Maybe you don't have latest version of tinymce?

Comment: Looks like tinymce wraps your pasted content inside the default tinymce block element (a div in your case). what happens if you paste inside the paragraph?

Comment: Aha, inside a paragraph it works fine, but I think I've found a related cause, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I revisited this problem and I figured it out.

It seems that through either something I did or through some bug from an action on TinyMCE (perhaps paste from Word?) a clearing div got wrapped around the content (or sometimes part of the content) and saved in the database that looked like this:

```
<div style="clear: both;">
    The content
</div>
```

Whenever a paste or a linebreak insert was done inside this div it cleared the rest of the content, and removing the div fixed the issue.

I'm sorry I cannot uncover what caused this but I hope that at least helps anyone searching.

***Edit***

I think this may have to do with pasting from word and the allowed tags in tinyMCE.
Using tinyMCE as a more fully fledged web page editor I believe it is good practice to include the following line in the initialization options:

```
valid_elements : '*[*]'
```

That will make tinyMCE allow any html tags you wish, and though I have yet to test it I believe this would also fix my pasting issue.